# Locating variables based on block diagram and its transfer function

Tags: control-theory

I have a diagram that looks like below:

[image]

I would like to find the variables $a$ and $b$ when the steady-state error becomes $0$ with unit acceleration as input $u(t) = \dfrac{t^2}{2}$.

I have found the following transfer function:

$$
  L(s) = \dfrac{as^2 + bs + 1}{s(s+2)(s+8)} \\
  G(s) = \dfrac{as^2 + bs + 1}{s^3 + 10s^2 + 16s + 1}
$$

In order to locate $a$ and $b$, I have written the following equation:

$$
  \begin{align*}
  E(s) = U(s) - Y(s) \\
  Y(s) = P(s)E(s) \\
  E(s) = \dfrac{1}{1 + P(s)}U(s) 
  \end{align*}
$$

$$
  \begin{align*}
     e_a & = \lim_{s\to0}sE(s)  = \lim_{s\to0}s\dfrac{1}{1+P(s)}R(s) \\ & = \lim_{s\to0}s*\dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{1}{s(s+2)(s+8)}}*\dfrac{1}{s^3}
  \end{align*}
$$

However, the above equation will be ∞, and cannot be $0$ in this case. What is wrong with my procedure? Could it be the transfer function that I wrote is incorrect? Can anyone help me to figure out this? Thank you for your time and suggestion.

Based on the suggestion that Mr. Rollen S. has given, the steady-state error can be written as below:

$$
  \begin{align*}
    e_a & = \lim_{s\to0}s\dfrac{s(s+2)(s+8) - (as^2+bs)}{s(s+2)(s+8)+1}*\dfrac{1}{s^3} \\ & = \lim_{s\to0}\dfrac{s^3+(10-a)^2+(16-b)s}{s(s+2)(s+8)+1}*\dfrac{1}{s^2} \\ & = \lim_{s\to0}\dfrac{s}{s(s+2)(s+8)+1} = 0
  \end{align*}
$$

with $a = 10, b = 16$.

Comment: Yes, your TF from $U$ to $E$ is incorrect. The standard formulas for the error TF do not apply here since this isn't "the standard" feedback loop (due to the feedforward). Derive it directly and show your work. One of us will point out the incorrect step or maybe you will find your mistake.

Comment: You remind me of the TF actually has an H(s) in the feedback system, I will try again.

Comment: As I know, the adder point and the feedback adder positions can be switched. Then, I move the feedback point before $C(s)$, therefore the feedback loop has a $H(s) = \dfrac{1}{as^2 + bs + 1}$. This is also how I derived the open and closed loop TF. However, it will be weird to derive $E(s)$ in this situation.

Comment: No matter how I rewrote the block diagram, it seems that the E(s) that I got are wrong. Perhaps the way I derived the diagram is already wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in the transfer function. First from the diagram we have that,

$$E(s) = U(s) - Y(s).$$

From the diagram we have that $Y(s) = P(s) \left( E(s) + C(s)\,U(s) \right)$ so,

$$E(s) = U(s) - P(s)\left( E(s) + C(s)\,U(s) \right).$$

Rewrite this as,

$$\left(1 + P(s)\right) E(s) = \left(1 - P(s)\,C(s)\right) U(s)$$

from which we deduce the transfer function from $U(s)$ to $E(s)$ is,

$$\frac{E(s)}{U(s)} = \frac{1 - P(s)\,C(s)}{1 + P(s)}.$$

Substituting your expressions for $P(s)$ and $C(s)$ yields,

$$\frac{E(s)}{U(s)} = \frac{s(s+2)(s+8) - (a s^2 + b s)}{s(s+2)(s+8) + 1}$$

If you simplify this, you can choose $a$ and $b$ so that this TF has a third-order zero at the origin which will cancel out with the poles of the given $u(t)$ which in turn achieves the objective of zero steady-state error.

Comment: It looks like I have made this whole block diagram too complex. Initially, I changed the diagram so that I can find the open/closed loop TF in the "standard way". I think that I am still lacking the power to derive TF in any block diagram even though I have practiced quite some. Thank you again for this concise solution!

Comment: Hi, if there is something like $H(s) = 1/k$ in the feedback loop, should it be considered into the $E(s)$? It looks like it should be, but if I look at the diagram, there seems no route between $Y(s)$ and $E(S)$ that will take $H(s)$ into account.

Comment: @Sonamu If you walk through the algebra of the diagram, it will most certainly appear.